# Characterizing that a system of $n$ linear equations with $n$ indeterminates has no solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and $b$ an $n \times 1$ matrix. 
If $n := 2$ and if $Ax = b$ is the system
$$x+y = 1,\ x + y = 2$$
of equations,
then $Ax = b$ has no solution. 
But $A^{\top}x = 0$,
which now is the system
$$x+y = 0,\ x + y = 0$$
of equations,
has infinitely many solutions.

So that we can characterize that a system of $n$ linear equations with $n$ indeterminates has no solution, is it true that
$Ax = b$ has no solution if and only if $A^{\top}x = 0$ has infinitely many solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conjecture is true:
The system $A^{\top}x = 0$ has infinitely many solutions iff rank$A^{\top} \leq m-1$ by the rank theorem and iff rank$A =$ rank$A^{\top} \leq m-1$; but the map $v \mapsto Av$ is surjective iff rank$A = m$; hence rank$A \leq m-1$ iff $v \mapsto Av$ is not surjective and iff there is some $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that $Ax = b$ is unsolvable.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. What you can say is that for $\;b\neq0\;$ , the square linear non-homogeneous system $\;Ax=b\;$ has **unique solution** iff the corresponding linear *homogeneous* system $\;Ax=0\;$ only has the trivial solution, or in the direction you tried: the non-hom. system $\;Ax=b\;$ has either no solution or infinite solutions iff the corresponding hom. sytem $\;Ax=0\;$ has infinite solutions.

The above is valid if we're working on an infinite field, of course.

Comment: Thanks very much. Would it hold if I weaken the formulation to be: For every $n \times n$ matrix $A$ there is an $n \times 1$ matrix $b$ such that $Ax = b$ has no solution if and only if $A^{\top}x = 0$ has infinitely many solutions? This seems possible?

Comment: @Chou That is completely accurate. Nice! Perhaps the name of "$\;n\times 1\;$ matrix " for the column vector $\;b\;$ is a little too fancy, though...:)

Comment: Is it possible for you to give a quick proof for the assertion?

Comment: @Chou Yes, but you must know some very basic stuff from linear algebra. **Proof 1** : a square matrix $\;n\times n\;$ can be seen as an operator $\;\Bbb F^n\to\Bbb F^n\;,\;\Bbb F\;$  a field (think of $\;\Bbb R\;\;or\;\;\Bbb C\;$ if you want), then we know it is an isomorphism iff it is injective iff it is onto, which means $\;Ax=b\;$ has a **unique** solution iff $\;A\;$ is a nisomorphism iff it is 1-1 iff $\;\ker A=\{0\}\;$ iff $\;Ax=0\;$ only has the trivial solution. **Proof 2**:  the rank of $\;A\;$ is $\;n\;$ iff its image is of dim. $\;n\;$ iff...and etc.

Comment: @Farnight Your statement "if $\;x\to Ax\;$ doesn't have infinite..." etc. is confusing at best, and wrong at worst: that $\;Ax=b\;$ does *not* have infinite solutions doesn't mean it can't be surjective. In fact, **any** isomorphism between finite dimensional linear spaces contradicts this.

Comment: @Timbuc: Many thanks. I know those stuff (but not fluent). As it seems to me, the equivalence you constructed seems not to prove the assertion? Per your equivalence, $Ax = 0$ iff $Ax = b$ does not have a unique solution, which is equivalent to "$Ax = b$ has no solution OR has infinitely many solutions", right?

Comment: @Chou, that is **your** assertion. What I find easier is that $\;Ax=b\;$ has a unique solution iff $\;Ax=0\;$ has a unique (the trivial) solution.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding :) By the assertion I mean this one "For every n×n matrix A there is an n×1 matrix b such that $Ax=b$ has no solution if and only if $A^{\top}x=0$ has infinitely many solutions", and you said "That is completely accurately"?

Comment: @Timbuc Yea, sorry about that. I really messed up that one.

Comment: @Chou Oh, that one: yes, since $\;Ax=0\;$ having infinite solutions means $\;A\;$ is **not** onto and thus there exists $\;b\;$ for which $\;Ax=b\;$ has no solution.

Comment: @Timbuc: Thanks. But sorry, I can understand the second part where "$A$ is not onto" is equivalent to "there is a $b$ such that $Ax = b$ has no solution", however I cannot understand the part before "thus". How do you tell "$Ax = 0$ having infinite solutions" is equivalent to "$A$ is not onto"? Thanks.

Comment: @Chou Because what I proved you in my first comment below my answer: $\;A\;$ is **not** onto iff $\;A\;$ is **not** one-to-one iff $\;\ker A\;$ contains more than the zero vector , and this means *infinite* elements over an infinite field.

Comment: @Timbuc: I think $A^{\top}x = 0$ is the case.